# Hook to change the site URL

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I am working on a WP system that is supposed to be served by multiple domains. For example, `foo.example.com` and `elpmaxe.com` point to the same installation. But depending on the URL, the system will conditionally serve a different landing page.

The question is, how do I make the `site_url()` just return the current URL, NOT the URL value from the database.

Comment: What is the "current URL" - the one that is being requested in the browser? Perhaps $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will help.

Comment: I don't have any problem figuring out the current URL. I have to make WP believe that the site URL is not the one in the database. I want site_url() to return whatever the current URL is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `site_url` using a filter - called `site_url`

The hook has the following signature:

```
apply_filters( 'site_url', string $url, string $path, string|null $scheme, int|null $blog_id )
```

You can use it like this:

```php
add_filter( 'site_url', 'wpse_381006_custom_site_url', 10, 1 );

function wpse_381006_custom_site_url( $url ){
    if( is_admin() ) // you probably don't want this in admin side
        return $url;

    // for example, return the request_uri - but this is not a complete solution, you would need to work out what you return and in what conditions..
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

}
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/site_url/